# Bitwise shift >= 32 operation for 64 bit variable in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make shift operation that is longer than 32 for 64 bit variable.
Can someone tell what is messed up with my code.

Processor architechture is AMD64 and development environments are Visual studio Community 2015 and DevC++

My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t x = ~0;
    printf("x is %8x \n", x);
    x = ~((uint64_t)(1) << 31);
    printf("x is %8x \n", x);
    x = ~((uint64_t)(1) << 32);
    printf("x is %8x \n", x);
    return 1;
}
```

Output is:

```
x is ffffffff
x is 7fffffff
x is ffffffff
```

I've been thinking on this for whole morning now..
I'm really a beginner with C on bigger than embedded 8-bit architechtures :)

-Codester

Comment: %x prints 32bit variable

Comment: Use a debugger, not printf

Comment: Maybe `%lx` for 64 bit. Or convert to `double` for `printf`.

Comment: printf("x is %8llX \n", x);// fixed my problem! Thanks guys!!

Comment: The correct format can be obtained by the *macro* `PRIx64`, something like `printf("x is %8"  PRIx64 "\n", x);`

Answer (score 4):

- `uint64_t x = ~0;`

  This code won't work if `int` is 32 bits. If you want to set a `uint64_t` to "all ones" in a portable manner, you need to do `uint64_t x = ~(uint64_t)0;`.
- `%8x`

  This is not the correct format specifier for `uint64_t`. You should use `PRIx64` from `inttypes.h`. Example:

  ```
  #include <inttypes.h>

  printf("x is %8" PRIx64 "\n", x);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Adding extra `llX` to printf format solved my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t x = ~0;
    printf("x is %8llX \n", x);
    x = ~((uint64_t)(1) << 31);
    printf("x is %8llX \n", x);
    x = ~((uint64_t)(1) << 32);
    printf("x is %8llX \n", x);
    return 1;
}
```

So many times answer is too simple :P